How to sum values within blocks with Postgres?
Given this table called prices:



my_date
my_value
my_separator




2012-02-10
100
1


2012-02-11
120
1


2012-02-12
120
1


2012-02-13
110
1


2012-02-14
100
0


2012-02-15
115
0


2012-02-16
130
1


2012-02-17
190
1


2012-02-18
180
1


2012-02-19
150
0


2012-02-20
130
1



I need to sum the values in my_value column based on the condition that my_separator is 1 within that group (so excluding the values where my_separator = 0). That should return the following values:

for the date range 2012-02-10-2012-02-13 => 100 + 120 + 120 + 110 = 450
for the date range 2012-02-16-2012-02-18 => 130 + 190 + 180 = 500
for the date 2012-02-20 => 130

I tried using window functions but I could not come up with anything valid. Any help?

really impossible to understand why this has been voted down and voted for closing. At least give an explanation.

SELECT min(my_date) AS start,
       max(my_date) AS stop,
       sum(my_value)
FROM (SELECT my_date,
             my_value,
             my_separator,
             count(*) FILTER (WHERE my_separator = 0)
                      OVER (ORDER BY my_date) AS grp
      FROM prices
     ) AS q
WHERE my_separator = 1
GROUP BY grp;

   start    │    stop    │ sum 
════════════╪════════════╪═════
 2012-02-10 │ 2012-02-13 │ 450
 2012-02-16 │ 2012-02-18 │ 500
 2012-02-20 │ 2012-02-20 │ 130
(3 rows)

